# WIX MSI : How to check screen resolution with Condition Tag

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to check (during the installation of my application) the resolution of the screen.

The minimal resolution has to be : 1366 * 768 – of course if it’s not the case, we have to display an error message.

I try to use this condition (without success) :

```
   <Condition Message="La RESOLUTION de votre ordinateur ne permet pas d'utiliser cette application (minimum : 1366 * 768) !">
         <![CDATA[Installed OR (ScreenX >= "1366" AND ScreenY >= "768")]]>
         </Condition>
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance

Fabrice

Answer (score 0):

Conditions need to evaluate to true for the install to proceed - it's a launch condition. What's Installed doing there? Currently your MSI will install only if it's already installed, which is unnecessary and causing the error. If the MSI is already installed you won't even get this far. You almost certainly never need to check Installed in a launch condition.

I don't think you need quotes around the values either - Windows can deal with the actual raw numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your response - i try this : <Condition Message="my message"> <![CDATA[ScreenX >= 1366 AND ScreenY >= 768]]> </Condition> - it's always the same problem ! At what moment the ScreenX property (or the ScreenY property) is initialized but the Windows Installer ?

Comment: Do the install with verbose log. msiexec /i <psth to msi file> /l*vx <path to text file> and see what the values are on your system. Those property values will be in the log.

Comment: ok i generated a verbose log and i have for example Property(S) ScreenX = 1024 and Property(C) ScreenX = 1920 - i want to use the Property(C) ScreenX  in my Condition tag and i think Windows installer use Property(S) ScreenX - Any ideas ?

Comment: If the ScreenX value in the log is 1024 and your condition includes ScreenX>=1366 then it works as intended. The install won't launch.

Comment: my current resolution screen is 1920 * 1080 (content of Property(C) ScreenX and ScreenY) ! i  just want check my current resolution screen, not the minimal resolution screen of my computer (probably 1024 * 768) - is it possible to check these values in a Condition Tag (or other Tag or Action) ?